# how to add this in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to combine fragment with activity. But I end up with an error.

**FRAGMENT CODE:**

```
public class QFragment extends Fragment {@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //returning our layout file
    //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_q, container, false);
}


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
        getActivity().setTitle("QFragment");
    }
}
```

One is being used as an activity other is a fragment. I am new to fragment concept.

**Main Activity code:**

```
    public class SpinnerEx4Activity extends Activity implements
    OnItemSelectedListener{
    Spinner s1,s2;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner_ex4);
            s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String sp1= String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
            Toast.makeText(this, sp1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(sp1.contentEquals("Income")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Salary");
                list.add("Sales");
                list.add("Others");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }
            if(sp1.contentEquals("Expense")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Conveyance");
                list.add("Breakfast");
                list.add("Purchase");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
```

So what is the way to solve this? I want the Bottom navigation bar in my app.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will put your implementation inside the fragment and make fragment transaction manager call it from the activity and here's code sample.
`

```
package com.bar.example.androidspinnerexample;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class SpinnerEx4Activity extends Activity implements
    OnItemSelectedListener{
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            QFragment fragment = new QFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            //container id as first param for replace function
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_spinner_ex4, fragment, null);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    }
```

and for the fragment

```
package com.blipclap.engineering_solution;

import android.content.Context;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class QFragment extends Fragment implements
    OnItemSelectedListener{@Nullable
            Spinner s1,s2;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //returning our layout file
    //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_q, container, false);
    s1 = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    s2 = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    return view;
}


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
        getActivity().setTitle("QFragment");
    }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String sp1= String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
            Toast.makeText(this, sp1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(sp1.contentEquals("Income")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Salary");
                list.add("Sales");
                list.add("Others");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }
            if(sp1.contentEquals("Expense")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Conveyance");
                list.add("Breakfast");
                list.add("Purchase");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

for the 3 errors you mentioned, please replace `this` with your class name
`SpinnerEx4Activity.this` for all three lines like this.

```
Toast.makeText(SpinnerEx4Activity.this, sp1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SpinnerEx4Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);



ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SpinnerEx4Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```